# setAuthenticateHandler failing to authenticate with Game Center

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, game-center

I'm new to iOS and trying to write a fun, turn-based iOS game. I'm trying to authenticate the local user right now and, while this code builds (albeit with a retain cycle warning), it always fails to authenticate with GameCenter.

```
// Authenticate the local user.
- (void)authenticateLocalUser
{
if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
[localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error)
{
    //[localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) { OLD CODE!
    if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
    {
        // Do some stuff.
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"NOT AUTHORISED"
                                  message:@"YOUR'RE NOT LOGGED INTO GC."
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
)];
```

}

My old code still works, but was depreciated in iOS6:

```
NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO)
{
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]
     authenticateWithCompletionHandler:nil];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511030/login-in-iphone-app-via-gamekit

Comment: That's not the same issue, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

That handler passes a UIViewController when the player is not authenticated. It is your responsibility to display the view controller if it receives one.

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    if (viewController != nil) {
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if (instance.player.isAuthenticated) {
        //Your handler will be called a second time once the user authenticates GC
        //using the view controller above ^^^^^
    } else if (error != nil) {
        //If all else fails, you'll have an error. Handle it
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that localPlayer, set outside/before the closure was not authenticated, while if I retrieved a new GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer() object, it would be authenticated.

```
func authenticatePlayer() {
  local_player.authenticateHandler = {(view_controller, error) -> Void in

    // Note that self.local_player.authenticated and 
    //  GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated give different
    //  results

    self.local_player = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    if (self.local_player.authenticated) {
      // Successfully authenticated
    } else if (view_controller != nil) {
      // Not yet authenticated
    } else {
      // authentication failed
    }
  }
}
```

In this instance, `local_player` is set in the surrounding class.

NOTE: I'm not actually sure why these give different results.